# MVC 4 Web Api Route 404 issue

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a plain-vanilla MVC 4 Web Api project created using VS2012.
The (/api/Values) works out-of-the-box on the **localhost** but NOT when deployed on **IIS** (packages created using the standard "Publish..." from the project menu).

After been through lot of articles and reading suggestion for similar issue I found the [Route tester](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) which visualized how IIS was interpreting the request.

[image: web api request on localhost vs. IIS]

As the screenshot revels, the IIS is interpreting *~/api/values* as *~/api/values.**aspx***

Any input on why this is happening and suggestion on how to resolve it is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Are the assemblies required for web api deployed to your bin folder?

Comment: Yes, I even marked all references as "copy local" and confirmed that all those assemblies are in the bin folder.

Comment: What about browsing locally on the server? Can you log in interactively, rpd?

Comment: Application is installed on the local IIS on Win7.
Route: {controller}/{action}/{id} works fine, only api/{controller}/{id} shows 404. While same application (code) works just perfect on localhost (IIS express)

Comment: Don't use IIS express on your dev machine (what OS?) and is the 'server' win7! Or, i'm not sure if I understand, are the issues you're seeing happening on the same machine, it's just you see the error in IIS, but NOT in IIS Express?

Comment: I'm developing on Win7 using VS2012. APP works fine when running in localhost (hit F5 in VS). BUT, when I make packages (via Publish feature) and deploy it to local IIS (IIS6.1, SP1) then only HomeController seems to be working. All other controllers inheriting from ApiController shows 404 error.

Comment: There is no IIS6.1 is there? Just go into the properties of the webapi project and under the web tab just untick 'Use IIS Express' rebuild and see if that helps.

Comment: Is the UrlRewriter module installed?